# I am able to send a post request in angular 11 app but how to retrieved data for particular input value

Tags: angular, http-post, fetch-api, rest

[question-task.image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00Qyn.png)

```
**check image question is listed**


<form #postForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onCreatePost(postForm.value)">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="title">Title</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            id="title"
            required
            ngModel
            name="marketname"
          />


onCreatePost(postData: { marketname: String }) {
    this.http.post(url,postData).subscribe(response=>{
      console.log(response)
    })
```

i am just able to print post request on browser console

but how to print data on browser from restapi having marketname="Web development"

Comment: Can you give more details ? Hard to understand your issue...

Comment: please check question-task image attached to understand my desired output

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I've understood what you've said but are you looking for something like this ?

```js
postForm: NgForm;

onCreatePost(postData: { marketname: string }) {
  this.http.post(url,postData).subscribe(response=>{
    console.log(response);
    postForm.setValue({ marketname: response }); // Maybe response.marketname
  });
}
```

Comment: check image and provide a solution to render in UI

Answer (score 0):

If you want to form a table as shown in your figure you can try this.Store the response from the api in a variable "data" , so that You Can Access it in your HTML. Write the below code after the form.

```
`
<form #postForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onCreatePost(postForm.value)">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="title">Title</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            id="title"
            required
            ngModel
            name="marketname"
          />
         </div>
         <button type="submit" >Search</button>
</form>
<ng-template *ngIf="data!=0">
        
       <table>
        
          <thead >
        
                    <tr>
                      <th scope="col">Market Name</th>
                      <th scope="col">Forecast Period</th>
                      <th scope="col">start Market Size</th>
                      <th scope="col">End Market Size</th>
                      <th scope="col">CAGR</th>
                      <th scope="col">Region</th>
                      <th scope="col">Currency</th>
                      <th scope="col">URL</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
            
                  <tbody>
                    <tr *ngFor="let item of data">
                      <td>{{item.MarketName}}</td>
                      <td>{{item.ForecastPeriod}}</td>
                      <td>{{item.startMarketSize}}</td>
                      <td>{{item.EndMarketSize}}</td>
                      <td>{{item.CAGR}}</td>
                      <td>{{item.Region}}</td>
                      <td>{{item.Currency}}</td>
                      <td>{{item.Region}}</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
            </table>
        
        <ng-template>
```

`

Comment: but where it is checking my post request with api
i think first I will send post request then then compare post request title with API and fetch it but how to do it I don't know

Comment: Declare a variable "data= 0" .Store the response from api in a variable "data" in "onCreatePost()" function. By doing so if "data" is not zero then the table will show with the json values.